# Konva.Node.create causes Stage to stop working

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I can create a stage and add shapes. However, if I use the Konva.Node.create command then the stage no longer displays newly added shapes.

In the code below, the first text 'Hello World !' is displayed, but the second text (after the Konva.Node.create) where it should display 'Hello World 2!' does not appear on the stage.

A working fiddle of this code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dxvh6zj8/6/).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container : "container",
    width : 400,
    height : 300
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);


var text = new Konva.Text({
  x: 10,
  y: 48,
  text:'Hello, World!',
  align: 'left',
  fontSize: 30,
  fontFamily: 'Calibri',
  fill: 'green',
  draggable: true,
  name: `text_${Date.now()}`
});
layer.add(text);
layer.draw();

Konva.Node.create(stage, "container");

var text2 = new Konva.Text({
  x: 40,
  y: 48,
  text:'Hello, World 2!',
  align: 'left',
  fontSize: 30,
  fontFamily: 'Calibri',
  fill: 'green',
  draggable: true,
  name: `text_${Date.now()}`
});
layer.add(text2);
layer.draw();
```

Comment: Please don't refer to offsite code. Instead, edit your question and insert a StackSnippet via the rightmost tool button in the editor.

Comment: In the light of @lavrton's answer I edited the question to make it more descriptive of the issue and imported the sample code from fiddle to make it a valid question.

Comment: Arjun - if the answer below was correct and helped you please accept it as the correct answer by clicking the tick button.  Marking an answer as correct adds value for other people who may search for this issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`Konva.Node.create` overwrites the original stage in div `container` and creates a new copy. So your changes are not visible.

Probably you just need to remove that line.

Comment: I want to store stage in database and recreate later and want to draw again. What is the solution

Comment: @ArjunKariyadan - please try to keep each question on one subject - if something not directly related comes up then ask another question on that subject.

Answer (score 0):

It worked!

```
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container : "container",
    width : 400,
    height : 300
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var text = new Konva.Text({
  x: 10,
  y: 48,
  text:'Hello, World!',
  align: 'left',
  fontSize: 30,
  fontFamily: 'Calibri',
  fill: 'green',
  draggable: true,
  name: `text_${Date.now()}`
});
layer.add(text);
layer.draw();

var stage = Konva.Node.create(stage, "container");
var layer = stage.getLayers()[0];

var text2 = new Konva.Text({
  x: 40,
  y: 48,
  text:'Hello, World 2!',
  align: 'left',
  fontSize: 30,
  fontFamily: 'Calibri',
  fill: 'green',
  draggable: true,
  name: `text_${Date.now()}`
});
layer.add(text2);
layer.draw();
```